# ListView not displayed in emulator but shows in Android studio?

Tags: android, listview, android-studio

The listView is displayed in Android Studio XML window but when I run it in GenyMotion, where the listView is supposed to be is empty. I tried adding dummy values but no luck.

add_device.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:weightSum="1">


       <EditText
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:id="@+id/deviceName"
        android:background="#c0c0c0"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="@dimen/abc_dialog_padding_material"
        android:hint="DEVICE NAME"
        android:layout_weight="0.73"
        android:editable="true"
        android:elegantTextHeight="false"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/listOfDevices"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/deviceName"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:divider="#33cc00"
        android:dividerHeight="2dp"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
        android:fastScrollAlwaysVisible="false"
        android:headerDividersEnabled="true"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:contextClickable="true"
        tools:listitem="@android:layout/simple_list_item_1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="140dp"
        android:listSelector="#33cc00"
        android:visibility="visible" />

        <Button
        android:layout_width="@dimen/abc_config_prefDialogWidth"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:text="CONFIRM"
        android:id="@+id/confirmBtn"
        android:layout_weight="0.76"
        android:background="#33cc00"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_marginBottom="22dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/companyTagName"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

       <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="PereGreen Energy Ltd"
        android:id="@+id/companyTagName"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        </RelativeLayout>
```

ListViewAndroidExample.Java

```
    public class ListViewAndroidExample extends Activity {
    ListView listView ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.add_device);

        // Get ListView object from xml
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listOfDevices);

        // Defined Array values to show in ListView
        String[] values = new String[] { "Test 1",
                "Test 2",
                "Test 3",
                "Test 4",
                "Test 5",
                "Test 6",
                "Test 7",
                "Test 8"
        };

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);


        // Assign adapter to ListView
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        // ListView Item Click Listener
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {

                // ListView Clicked item index
                int itemPosition     = position;

                // ListView Clicked item value
                String  itemValue    = (String) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);

                // Show Alert
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Position :" + itemPosition + "  ListItem : " + itemValue, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();

            }

        });
    }

}
```

This is what I see when I run the emulator.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you just can't see the items because of the text color? Does your `Toast` show if you click?

Comment: I just changed the background color of the ListView to red to see if it would display, it does! But it's just a empty square, no items in it? Should I not be seeing 'test 1, test 2' etc.? Maybe something wrong in my code where I am adding to the list?

Comment: If you can see the red `ListView`, then yeah, you should be seeing the items. Maybe some glitch in your emulator. You might try temporarily removing the `EditText`, `TextView`, and `Button`. Failing that, run it on a device.

Comment: It is. Your code is fine. I just copied/pasted it to test your layout, and it works on my device.

Comment: Alright. Will try that.  Let you know how it goes in 2 minutes.

Comment: Can you also see the items in the listView and scroll through them?

Comment: Yep. It works as I would expect from your given code.

Comment: Tried what you suggested, no luck.  Could it be the emulator I am using, maybe the phone device I chose, the resolution and stuff?

Comment: I'm not sure what to tell you. As I said, I just copied/pasted and ran it, apart from changing two attributes in the XML - the `EditText`'s `textSize`, and the `Button`'s `layout_width`. If your `Toast` shows when you click, then it's a problem with the layout. If it doesn't, I would have to say that that's not the code you're currently running. You might try cleaning/rebuilding your project.

Comment: Alright.  I will try that and review the code once more.  I bet it's something silly.  I appreciate all the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List <String> sampleValues= new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(values));
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, sampleValues);


        // Assign adapter to ListView
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Let me know in case of any query.